# Two monitors - resolution not correct

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have two monitors that are exactly the same make and model but obviously with different inputs...I am trying to get them working in Ubuntu 14.04. Here is some output from a random command I found:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 connected primary 1280x1024+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1
```

As you can see the `VGA1` input isn't picking up the correct resolution. Is there any way I can force the resolution to be 1280x1024.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following file: `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45setoutput`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
```

Restarted, then set the resolution in the GUI menu.